# Invoke a C# webservice through javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a C# `[Web Method]` stored at the url below, but I don't seem to be having any luck pinging it. The return is a `List<string>`. What am I doing wrong with this service call"?

## Asp.Net designer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://staging.ws/service.asmx/AutoDatax",
                    data: "{'searchText':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, msg, e) {
                        alert(xhr.response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input  id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" value="<% =searchTerm  %>"" class="autosuggest" />
    <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" class="standardButton" OnClick="searchButton_Click" Text="Search"/>
</div>
```

## And here's the web service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    static string db = Connect.Connect("Search", false);
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> AutoDatax(string searchText)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(db))
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE SearchTerm LIKE @SearchText + '%';", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", searchText);
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["SearchTerm"].ToString());
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this url `http://staging.ws/service.asmx/AutoDatax` different from what you have in your current browser ? I mean the path can be different but the protocol, hostName and port of  the your address bar url, are they same ? If not then you're limited by Same Origin Policy. You can check the status of Ajax call in `Chrome - Developer Tools (F12) - Network - Filter by XHR`

Comment: Any error messages in the browser's console? Does the webmethod get executed?

Comment: @HansKesting I believe it is executed because when I invoke it manually (via SOAP UI), it returns the correct results without error.

Comment: @Arkantos or in every other major browser with the dev tools (F12).

Comment: @Mouser.. I know that F12 works in most browsers, I just want to make it easier for OP :)

Comment: SOAP UI is not restricted by Same Origin Policy, it just fires a request

Comment: @Arkantos By automatically assuming he's using Chrome? ;-)

Comment: @Arkantos, yes if appears to be the same.

Comment: @Mouser, assumption would be correct in this case. I am on Chrome atm.

Comment: When invoking though SoapUI works, then at least the webmethod itself is correct. But is it called correctly from your ajax call? That is, does your webpage fail on calling the webmethod or on recieving the answer?

Comment: @Mouser.. If I was assuming that he's using Chrome then I wouldn't have mentioned Chrome in my answer, isn't it ? ;) Let's just leave it here and concentrate on OP's issue :)

Comment: @HansKesting No failures anywhere. The textbox just spins. No fail message, nothing. When I received errors locally, it always popped up the `alert()` box. Nothing happens now though, just spins.

Comment: Do you see the status code of your Ajax call in Network tab ? What does it say ? Any errors in Console ? One more thing, if you're expecting `json` response just set `contentType: "application/json"`, charset is usually with text based responses

Comment: @Arkantos Okay, I just checked it out and it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of null` and `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:52894' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Haha.. when I asked you if protocol, hostName and port no are same, you said they are same ;) that's the problem, as the host name and port no are different, browser will send an additional `Origin` request header but your server is not responding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, so you're response will not be considered.

Comment: @Arkantos Okay, yeah my fault. Kind of new to this stuff... if it tells you anything I honestly have no clue what you just said. Me != network savvy. So what do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: If you're running your code in an actual server, then we could have just added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-host-name` in your C# server side response, but you're running it on localhost, so we cannot use as localhost doesn't have any meaning outside your system. One thing I can suggest is add a new URL mapping in your local server, that will internally call your `http://staging.ws/service.asmx/AutoDatax` web service

Comment: You can even try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-ip-address` in C# response but for that to work with `localhost` you have to change your `hosts` file, should be a simple change from your side, not sure if you can change C# response to add that header